# How to build WebKit on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, macos, cocoa, webkit

I have built `WebKit` on Mac, but I want to build it on iPhone.

Should I convert Cocoa framework to CocoaTouch framework?

Like `NSView` to `UIView`?

or any other functions?

Answer (score 3):

There are certainly going to be things not directly translatable from Cocoa to UIKit. Yes the core of Webkit is mostly platform-independent C++, however, all the nice views will require a lot more work than just class replacement. More than just internal mechanics, you also have to deal with completely redesigning the views for the iOS interface--handling touches for scrolling and zooming, getting input forms and text selection to work with the system-wide text protocols, etc.

Unless you have to do something ridiculously complicated, just stick with UIWebView.